What happened to the Sudanese pound in 2023?
Looking at the Sudanese pound to USD exchange rate history,

there is a peculiar trend of devaluation over time. According to Wikipedia:

The Sudanese pound was devalued on 23 February 2021, with the official (indicative) exchange rate set to LS 375.08 per US dollar (from the fixed rate of LS 55), closing the gap between the commercial and black market exchange rates.

with no further information. It looks like another "readjustment" was done in July 22 to ~570, but then this odd trend happened until it stabilized (for a while) at ~600.
What happened at the start of 2023, or at least, what causes such a movement in a currency's value?
